# Angular ng-options behaves odd

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-strap

I have this typahead with angular strap:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="newGroupForm.placeReference.$invalid ? 'has-error' : ''">
    <label for="placeReference" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Group Location</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" name="placeReference" 
               ng-model="newGroup.reference" 
               ng-options="place.reference as place.name 
                           for place in getPlaces($viewValue)" 
               bs-typeahead min-length="0" required >
    </div>
</div>
```

`getPlaces` returns array of objects which looks like this:

```
{
   reference: "ccj32213SIJD",
   name: "some name",
}
```

When I am typing I am getting correct results, but when I select the wonted option the value that I see in my input is the reference (instead of the name).

Can any one point out my mistake?

[image: suggestions]
[image: reference instead of name]

Here is the controller code:

```
$scope.getPlaces = function(viewValue) {
    var input = viewValue || $scope.currentPlace;
    return googleService.placesAutocomplete(input).then(
        function(places) {
            return places;
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: add another variable to your scope and set your ng-model to it, something simple like test, no properties, and see what it returns

Comment: I have added an id (which is holding the same as the reference)- still the same result

Comment: i meant just save it to a string not an object property

Comment: Can you give me an example

Comment: I set ng-model="test" and it still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ng-options` here behaves exactly like `<select ng-options>` (sorry, I'm not familiar with `bs-typeahead` directive), then you should change it to:

```
<input ... 
    ng-model="selectedPlace" 
    ng-options="place as place.name for place in getPlaces($viewValue)">
```

Then you can use get the name elsewhere:

```
<div>{{selectedPlace.name}}</div>
```

It's probably best to get the actual `place` object `{name: "..", reference: "..."}`, but if you just need the name, then you could do this:

```
<input ... 
        ng-model="selectedPlaceName" 
        ng-options="place.name as place.name for place in getPlaces($viewValue)">
```

Comment: Now when I am just doing ng-model="selected place" and selecting the place object . after selecting the input is cleared

Comment: You'd need to create a plunker - it's not easy to understand what is going on.

Comment: I would be happy to create one, but it is hard because all of the dependencies

Comment: Well, you could link to dependencies, if they are hosted on cdn. And reduce your code to bare minimum to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I will try, it will take some time